# Redis Cluster over Kubernetes with Failover issue

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am a complete newbie to Redis and K8. We have a 6 nodes Redis cluster (3 masters, 3 replicas), and I have noticed an issue that when a replica pod goes down and then automatically re-created by K8 - it does join the cluster as a replica (as expected), however we seem to loose all data - redis server memory metrics go to 0 for all masters and we have only cache misses (no hits). We use the `redis-server "$CONF_FILE" --bind "$MY_POD_IP"` on the newly created pod; the config file:

```
port 0
tls-port 6379
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
logfile "/logs/redis.log"
bind $MY_POD_IP
tls-cert-file /etc/runit/tls/redis-cert.pem
tls-key-file /etc/runit/tls/redis-key.pem
tls-ca-cert-file /etc/runit/tls/redis-cert.pem
tls-auth-clients yes
tls-replication yes
tls-cluster yes
tls-protocols "TLSv1.2"
tls-ciphers DEFAULT:!MEDIUM
```

The logs of the new replica:

```
14:C 10 Oct 2023 22:58:19.498 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
14:C 10 Oct 2023 22:58:19.498 # Redis version=6.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=14, just started
14:C 10 Oct 2023 22:58:19.498 # Configuration loaded
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:58:19.500 * No cluster configuration found, I'm b061c6928a315d4c59d92b790664ba317f0d2ae8
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:58:19.502 * Running mode=cluster, port=6379.
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:58:19.502 # Server initialized
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:58:19.503 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo madvise > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled (set to 'madvise' or 'never').
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:58:19.503 * Ready to accept connections
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:01.808 # configEpoch set to 6 via CLUSTER SET-CONFIG-EPOCH
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:02.168 # IP address for this node updated to 10.90.0.13
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:03.888 * Before turning into a replica, using my own master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:03.889 # Cluster state changed: ok
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.622 * Connecting to MASTER 10.90.3.139:6379
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.622 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.667 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.667 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.668 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request 5259d3c51c51651557847e725347a42ca7457791:1).
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.840 * Full resync from master: aa0db4f142aecd448628b1450e1edf792aaa15fa:147464307149
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.840 * Discarding previously cached master state.
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.899 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 340 bytes from master to disk
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.900 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.900 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.900 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.8
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.900 * RDB age 0 seconds
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.900 * RDB memory usage when created 26.77 Mb
14:S 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.900 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Finished with success
```

The master node logs:

```
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:27:02.521 * Marking node d67417fd172cb92aeefed170fe445185b8e7271d as failing (quorum reached).
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:00.729 # Cluster state changed: fail
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.668 * Replica 10.90.0.13:6379 asks for synchronization
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.668 * Partial resynchronization not accepted: Replication ID mismatch (Replica asked for '5259d3c51c51651557847e725347a42ca7457791', my replication IDs are 'aa0db4f142aecd448628b1450e1edf792aaa15fa' and '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.668 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.669 * Background saving started by pid 22156
22156:C 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.760 * DB saved on disk
22156:C 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.855 * RDB: 1537 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.899 * Background saving terminated with success
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:04.899 * Synchronization with replica 10.90.0.13:6379 succeeded
14:M 10 Oct 2023 22:59:06.810 # Cluster state changed: ok
```

I expected th replica to join the cluster without any effect. Any suggestions on why the new replica causes us to flush the cache?